# HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified - causing the server socket and client socket to close

Tags: c#, http, sockets, tcp

I have a custom TCP Server listening on port 5888(dummy port). The proxy server listens for incoming connections. When the proxy receives HTTP request for certain pages, it should relay it to the main server on port 80.For other page requests the proxy is required to send data to the main Server on port 8081.

The clients request for a .js file from the proxy. The proxy sends the same request to the main server on port 80. The main server is sending this message back along with Connection: Close.

```
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Wed, 10 Oct 2012 10:45:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat)
Connection: close
ETag: "748047-11f4f-4b8dc565b9100"
```

Which is causing the server and client sockets to disconnect (Detected Server Socket disconnect via read)

How to handle this situation ?

Comment: it is hard to know where the problem is without seeing code.  The non 200 response could be causing an exception which you are not catching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem here to 'handle'. The server said to close the connection, and closed it itself. So close it, after you send that response back to the client, and close the connection to the client too. It's not your job as a proxy server to fiddle around with this, not that you can.

Answer (score 4):

The socket is being closed because that is the end of the response.  There is nothing more for the server to send.

How you handle it depends on what result you want.  The response indicates that the far client included an "if-modified-since" header field so you should be able to simply pass *this* response directly back to that client and be done with it.